# How do you handle it if you don't upload photos on vue Js?

Tags: vue.js

How do you handle it if you don't upload photos on vue Js ?? .. I have an article edit case, when I edit an article, usually only the content of the article is edited, otherwise it's just the name of the article title, it's seldom to update the photo ... well, for example, if the photo is not updated / empty, how do I handle it her? I wan't if picture not upload, then old picture not change.. if empty error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"` ..

this is my code

```
let formData = new FormData();
if (this.$refs.file.files[0] != null){
    formData.append(
        "img",
        this.$refs.file.files[0],
        this.$refs.file.files[0].name
    );
} else {
    // this here in what content ?
}
```

Comment: Try something like `if(typeof this.$refs.file.files[0] !== 'undefined') {`

Comment: @ceejayoz how to the in else ? how the code ?

Comment: That's up to you. Do whatever you like there.

Comment: @ceejayoz how if not upload picture, then old picture not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `this.$ref` . try to make the `formData property in data function`  and loop through key value object

```
//this is my example straight from my project
  data() {
    return {
      formData: {
        id: null,
        patient_id: this.patient.id,
        admission_date: "",
        discharge_date: "",
        provider: "",
        hospital: "",
        reason: "",
        attachment: null,
      },
    };
  },
    methods: {
    submitFormData() {
      let form = new FormData();

// here when data is submitted formData key value is being looped through new FormData
      for (var key in this.formData) {
        form.append(key, this.formData[key]);
      }
      axios
        .post("api.example.com/store", form, {
          header: {
            "Content-Type":
              "multipart/form-data"
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
    },
```

file attachment is `attachment:null` in this case initially